# No class template specialization for array of bool?

Tags: c++, stdvector, template-specialization, stdarray, class-template

According to https://en.cppreference.com/, `std::vector<bool>` has a class template specialization, while `std::array<bool, N>` does not. Which are the reasons why it is not provided?

Comment: Because this is already provided by `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When `std::vector` was introduced, a specialization for `bool` was considered a good idea. Basically, at that time, the average computer had 4 MB of memory, so saving computer memory was quite important. Nowadays we just say "memory is cheap" (quote from Uncle Bob).

Later it turned out that this specialization creates more problems than it is worth.

The issue is that the address to one of the elements of such a vector is a complex object (it has to store information on which bit holds which value) compared to regular old-fashioned C-array `bool a[]`.

Since compatibility must be retained, this specialization can't be dropped, but based on that lesson, the same approach was not applied to `std::array`.

Another reason is that `std::array` is supposed to be a C-array wrapper, so it must be as similar to `bool a[N]` as possible, and must produce the same machine code when used.

And the last thing, as Cody Gray points out in [a comment under question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862197/no-class-template-specialization-for-array-of-bool#comment114677136_64862197), `std::bitset` is a constant size array of bits, so such functionality is already available (and can be used if needed).

Comment: Excellent answer, +1. However, please don’t use code formatting for non-code text: it can interfere with alternative browsing technology, e.g. screen readers for the blind, and so make the site less accessible.

Answer (score 14):

This is a question about history of evolution of C++. In hindsight a possible explanation is:

`std::vector<bool>` was a mistake. It is a major annoyance that a `std::vector<bool>` is very different from `std::vector<T>`. Generic code that works with `vector`s often needs a special case for `std::vector<bool>`. And users often have to apply weird workarounds like using a `std::vector<char>` in place of `std::vector<bool>`. Now we cannot go back without breaking lots of existing code. With what we know now, maybe `std::vector<bool>` would never have made it into C++.

`std::array` was added only in C++11. There was no reason to make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 9):

The initial motivation to specialize `std::vector` for `bool` was to optimize memory usage.

However this was a bad idea as this specialization behaves differently than usual `std::vector` (see example below).

This error was not reproduced later with C++11's `std::array`

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> i_v(4);
  int i_a = *&i_v[3]; // ok

  std::vector<bool> v(4);
  bool a = *&v[3]; // Compile-time error

  std::array<bool,4> w;
  bool b = *&w[3]; // ok
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `std::vector<bool>` specialization was introduced as early as 1994, as per [lib.vector.bool](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/lib-containers.html#lib.vector.bool) of [WG21/N0545](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/wp/html/sep94/coversheet.html)<sup>(1)</sup> [**emphasis** mine]:

> **23.1.6  Class `vector<bool>` [lib.vector.bool]**
>
> **To optimize space allocation**, a specialization for `bool` is provided: [...]

with a motivation to optimize for space allocation, a resource that was sparse back then.

In retrospect, this turned out to be quite a bad idea, and the original motivation was made moot with the rapid growth of available space in computer hardware.

`std::array`, on the other hand, was introduced much later, in C++11, alongside e.g. `auto` type deduction, a mechanism which highlighted yet another problem with the `std::vector<bool>` specialization. Naturally the library spec writers did not repeat the same mistake of `std::vector<bool>` when designing `std::array`.

E.g., the following snippet

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> v{false, false, true, true};
    auto bool_value = v[1];
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(bool_value), bool>, "");  // Error!
}
```

fails with the error message that `bool_value` is not of type `bool`, but of the cryptic type (implementation-defined)

> ```
> error: static_assert failed due to requirement
> 'std::is_same_v<
>     std::__1::__bit_reference<
>         std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool>>, true>, 
>     bool>' ""
> ```

---

<sub>(1) *Working Paper for Draft Proposed International Standard for Information Systems-- Programming Language C++.*</sub>