std::span of a vector<bool> doesn't compile
Let's preface it by stating once again that std::vector<bool> was a mistake.
But now it finally bit me. This doesn't compile:
LiveDemo
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> intvec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto vec_int_view = std::span(intvec);

      // This will not compile:
//    std::vector<bool> boolvec = { true, false, true, true };
//    auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
}

Errors:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:13:43: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
<source>:13:43: error: no matching function for call to 'span(std::vector<bool>&)'
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:233:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _OType, long unsigned int _OExtent>  requires (_Extent == std::dynamic_extent || _OExtent == std::dynamic_extent || _Extent == _OExtent) && (std::__is_array_convertible<_Type, _OType>::value) span(const std::span<_OType, _OExtent>&)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  233 |         span(const span<_OType, _OExtent>& __s) noexcept
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:233:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'const std::span<_OType, _OExtent>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:225:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent> span(const std::span<_Tp, _Num>&)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  225 |       span(const span&) noexcept = default;
      |       ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:225:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'const std::span<_Tp, _Num>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:213:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _Range>  requires !(__is_span<typename std::remove_cvref<_I2>::type>) && !(__is_std_array<typename std::remove_cvref<_I2>::type>) && !(is_array_v<typename std::remove_cvref<_I2>::type>) && (contiguous_range<_Range>) && (sized_range<_Range>) && ((borrowed_range<_Range>) || (is_const_v<_Type>)) && (std::__is_compatible_ref<decltype(*(declval<decltype(std::ranges::__access::__begin((declval<_Range&>)()))&>)())>::value) span(_Range&&)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  213 |         span(_Range&& __range)
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:213:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Type'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:201:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _Tp, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent>  requires  std::span<_Tp, _Num>::__is_compatible_array::value span(const std::array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>&)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  201 |         span(const array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>& __arr) noexcept
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:201:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'const std::array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:194:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _Tp, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent>  requires  std::span<_Tp, _Num>::__is_compatible_array::value span(std::array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>&)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  194 |         span(array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>& __arr) noexcept
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:194:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'std::array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:187:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent>  requires  _Extent == std::dynamic_extent || _ArrayExtent == _Extent span(std::type_identity_t<_Type> (&)[_ArrayExtent])-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  187 |         span(type_identity_t<element_type> (&__arr)[_ArrayExtent]) noexcept
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:187:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   mismatched types 'std::type_identity_t<_Type> [_ArrayExtent]' and 'std::vector<bool>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:172:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _It, class _End>  requires (contiguous_iterator<_It>) && (sized_sentinel_for<_End, _It>) && ((std::__is_compatible_ref<decltype(*(declval<_I2&>)())>::value) && !(is_convertible_v<_End, long unsigned int>)) span(_It, _End)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  172 |         span(_It __first, _End __last)
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:172:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:157:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent, class _It>  requires (contiguous_iterator<_It>) && (std::__is_compatible_ref<decltype(*(declval<_I2&>)())>::value) span(_It, std::size_t)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
  157 |         span(_It __first, size_type __count)
      |         ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:157:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:149:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent> span()-> std::span<_Type, _Extent> requires  _Extent == std::dynamic_extent || _Extent == 0'
  149 |       span() noexcept
      |       ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:149:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:54:11: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _Extent> span(std::span<_Type, _Extent>)-> std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
   54 |     class span;
      |           ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:54:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'std::span<_Type, _Extent>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:466:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Range>  requires  contiguous_range<_Range> std::span(_Range&&)-> span<typename remove_reference<ranges::range_reference_t<_Range&> >::type>'
  466 |     span(_Range &&)
      |     ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:466:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:466:5: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/compare:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:56,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/ostream:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/iostream:41,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/concepts: In substitution of 'template<class _Range>  requires  contiguous_range<_Range> std::span(_Range&&)-> span<typename remove_reference<ranges::range_reference_t<_Range&> >::type> [with _Range = std::vector<bool>&]':
<source>:13:43:   required from here
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/concepts:74:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'derived_from<typename std::__detail::__iter_concept_impl<_Iter>::type, std::contiguous_iterator_tag>' [with _Iter = std::_Bit_iterator]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:697:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'contiguous_iterator<decltype (std::ranges::__access::__begin(declval<_Container&>()))>' [with _Tp = std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:607:13:   required for the satisfaction of 'contiguous_range<_Range>' [with _Range = std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/concepts:74:28: note:   'std::contiguous_iterator_tag' is not a base of 'std::random_access_iterator_tag'
   74 |     concept derived_from = __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:462:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iter, class _End>  requires  contiguous_iterator<_Iter> std::span(_Iter, _End)-> span<typename remove_reference<iter_reference_t<_Tp> >::type>'
  462 |     span(_Iter, _End)
      |     ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:462:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:458:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent> std::span(const array<_Tp, _Nm>&)-> span<const _Type, _ArrayExtent>'
  458 |     span(const array<_Type, _ArrayExtent>&)
      |     ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:458:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:455:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent> std::span(array<_Tp, _Nm>&)-> span<_Tp, _Num>'
  455 |     span(array<_Type, _ArrayExtent>&) -> span<_Type, _ArrayExtent>;
      |     ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:455:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   'std::vector<bool>' is not derived from 'std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:452:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Type, long unsigned int _ArrayExtent> std::span(_Type (&)[_ArrayExtent])-> span<_Tp, _Num>'
  452 |     span(_Type(&)[_ArrayExtent]) -> span<_Type, _ArrayExtent>;
      |     ^~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/include/c++/14.2.0/span:452:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:43: note:   mismatched types '_Type [_ArrayExtent]' and 'std::vector<bool>'
   13 |     auto vec_bool_view = std::span(boolvec);
      |                                           ^

What are my options here? Just use std::vector<uint8_t>?
I almost thought I could finally make use of this vector optimisation.. :/

std::vector<bool> is not a contiguous container/range and std::span implements a view into a contiguous range

so yeah, that simply doesn't match

If you want the memory optimization provided by std::vector<bool>, then std::span is not an option. For what do you need the span?

@user17732522 I want one container to get a view into the other without breaking the API

Why do you use vector<bool> at all ? It is usually not recommended, excpet for specific cases. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al.

@wohlstad Basically it keeps track of which LED's in my firmware are turned on/off.

By default I would simply use std::vector<uint8_t>, which supports spans etc. You can also have a look at std::bitset.

You can just use views::all to convert the vector into view like https://godbolt.org/z/savqd1M9c.

Do you actually have a variable number of LEDs in your firmware? If not, just use std::array<bool, N> instead

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862281/1387438

@Useless Yes and no, the firmware matches multiple hardwares that ship with different amount of LED's. I could hardcode it (as an ifdef) but then I'd need to template half of my code on the LED numbers which I don't like.

std::span:

describes an object that can refer to a contiguous sequence of objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero.

This means std::span<T> can refer to a contigous sequences of Ts.
However std::vector<bool>:

Does not necessarily store its elements as a contiguous array.

So the two do not match.
Morover - std::vector<bool> is not a proper std container at all, since it does not guarantee all the Container requirements.
If it's important for you to use a span into the sequence, I would go with std::vector<uint8_t>.
If it's not a must, and you want to keep memory footprint compact, you can have a look at std::bitset.
In any case I would not use std::vector<bool> if I have a choice.
See more about it here: Is the use of std::vector<bool> objects in C++ acceptable, or should I use an alternative?.

std::vector<bool> is not a proper std container at all. sure it is. Its just not a std::vector ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai my text is an over simplification, but the post I linked mentions that it doesn't conform to all the std container requirements.

I think that std::vector<std::uint_least8_t> would be a better suggestion, as it's more portable and doesn't depend on any using.

@TobySpeight I was not aware that uint8_t requires a using, nor that is it less portable than uint_least8_t. They are both listed together here. Are you sure ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai std::vector< bool > does not guarantee the Container requirement (and a couple other requirements), so no, it's not a Container. ;-)

@DevSolar yep, in the meantime I understood what the answer says. As usual I will leave my wrong comment to keep context for the correcting comments and to save others from the same mistake ;)

Assuming you include <cstdint> rather than the deprecated <stdint.h>, then uint8_t is in the std namespace.  So you need using if you need it in the global namespace.  std::uint_least8_t is more portable because it is always provided, whereas std::uint8_t is provided only if the target has an 8-bit type without padding.

@TobySpeight interesting - good to know I'll keep it in mind. However - as long as you #include <cstdint> - all 3 main compilers are happy to let you use uint8_t without std:: and without using. See demo.

I think I'm settling for bitset. Basically I'll use it as bookkeeping information of which channels are already set for the led.

Coding for "all three main compilers" (presumably GCC, Clang and ICC) isn't a good approach to writing portable software!  Perhaps just my opinion, but I reckon it's better to write something definitively correct than merely good enough for what I happen to have to hand.

@glades bitset is a decent choice for representing flags-like data. But it doesn't support using as a span. It also requires the number of bits at compile time (as a template argument).

@TobySpeight fair enough. BTW - I was referring to MSVC as the third "main" compiler.
